# Can I run a windows presentation foundation app the way I would run a aspnet app?

Tags: asp.net, wpf

Can I run a windows presentation foundation app on a webserver over the internet, or does it run like a windows app where I have to download the code to each pc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mgroves mentioned, Silverlight is one alternative to a desktop-based WPF app. You might also be interested in WPF Browser Applications. You get all of the features of WPF (Silverlight only gives you a subset) with the ease of deployment via a webserver and a traditional rich client development experience. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx) for more information.

Comment: This requires the user to use ActiveX, which I believe restricts them to using IE.  Silverlight, as you mentioned, is a subset, but has plugins (or will have plugins) for all major browsers.

Comment: @mgroves

XBAP and ActiveX are two different technologies. XBAPs will run in Firefox as well.

Answer (score 1):

WPF apps are traditional "desktop" apps.  If you want a very similar experience on the web though, then use Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.  There is a method to run small WPF apps through the browser in the form of an [XBAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx) executable.
This will still download some code to the pc, but then the app runs in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a WPF app that runs through the browser. In visual studio 2008, go to new project, click to create a new windows project. You should see an option to create a WPF browser application. This is different then using silverlight but it plays in the same sandbox as silver light, meaning that it can not access the users harddrive among other things. More info can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx)

Silverlight is another option that is much like flash.

I do not know the pros/cons of running a WPF browser application off the top of my head but the link I posted should have some good info.

I was looking around for pros and cons of using a WPF browser app and stumbled across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251718/silverlight-wpf-web-app-xbap-or-click-once-pros-and-cons). It is the pros and cons of WPF app, WPF browser app, and silver light.