# Converting Existing Projects to Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

We are planning to convert all our projects into Silverlight Technology.
After doing some research work we came to know that there are some Plug-In Isssues related with Silverlight.
Will it be a good idea to convert project in still developing Technology like Silverlight.
Can anyone pointout some Advantages and Disadvantages of Silverlight.

Thanks.

Comment: Convert from? What type of applications?

Comment: We Have Applications developed in Visual Studio 2008(C#.Net)

Comment: Is the existing applications webbased or windows applications?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I believe that most technologies are more or less under development. Silverlight have become a modern and mature technology that are superior to many other webbased technologies.

Silverlight requires a plugin in the browser to run. The penetration of the plugin is about 75% worldwide - depending on your kind of application this will not be an issue for you. Earlier this year I wrote a post about this particular issue (https://thomasmartinsen.com/2011/01/23/the-silverlight-penetration-is-no-longer-an-issue/).

I will recommend you read about Silverlight on http://silverlight.net or take a look at this discussion here on stackoverflow: [Silverlight, Wpf Web App (xbap) or Click Once? Pros and Cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251718/silverlight-wpf-web-app-xbap-or-click-once-pros-and-cons)